# Create function to create thambnails of available images in a folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image, directory, thumbnails

I have create a CMS to upload all image to a folder using ed all my images to a folder using,

```
file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../images/") + advertID.ToString + "_" + i.ToString + fileExt)
```

Now, all images are saved and i forgot it create thumbnails. :(

I need to read all images at once and create thumbnails,

```
myimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imgFileName)
myimg = myimg.GetThumbnailImage(154, 94, Nothing, IntPtr.Zero)
myimg.Save(Server.MapPath("../Content/") + "Thumb_" + imgFileName, myimg.RawFormat)
```

I need this to function fast. I don't seems to know how to read these image names one by one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have a compiled version of this?source code?

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified version of [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2004/06/23/162913.aspx):

```
public void createThumbnails(string sourceDir) 
{
    //Process the list of files found in the directory. 
    string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);

    foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
    {
        //Do resizing here.
        myimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileName);
        myimg = myimg.GetThumbnailImage(154, 94, Nothing, IntPtr.Zero);
        myimg.Save(Server.MapPath("../Content/") + "Thumb_" + fileName, myimg.RawFormat);
    }
}
```

Called like this:

```
createThumbnails("C:\Path\To\Images");
```

***Edit**: VB.NET equivalent using [converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) tool:

```
Public Sub createThumbnails(ByVal sourceDir As String)
    Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir)

    For Each fileName As String In fileEntries
        myimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileName)
        myimg = myimg.GetThumbnailImage(154, 94, [Nothing], IntPtr.Zero)
        myimg.Save((Server.MapPath("../Content/") & "Thumb_") + fileName, myimg.RawFormat)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Im getting this error (I want to use it in VB.net)

Compiler Error Message: BC30369: Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.

Source Error:
Line 25:             myimg.Save(Server.MapPath("/images/") + "Thumb_" + fileName, myimg.RawFormat)

Source File: G:\wwwroot\srilancars\createThumbs.aspx.vb    Line: 25

Comment: Remove the (C#: static, VB.NET: shared) in the function definition to solve the problem, i.e: public void createThumbNails() instead of public static void createThumbnails(). VB.NET: Public Sub createThumbnails() instead of Public Shared Sub. Updated my answer.

Comment: Now I am getting this error:

Exception Details: System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory.

Source Error:
Line 24:             myimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileName)

Source File: G:\wwwroot\srilancars\createThumbs.aspx.vb    Line: 24

Comment: How many images are you trying to resize and what size are they? Can your machine handle it all?

Comment: these images are basically between 200 - 400 k. and i am testing with few images. I have a windows 2003 server running with QuadCore Processor, 4 gb ram.